# How to set a free (gratis) SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl

I have the following set of instructions on how to bootstrap a website hosting environment

```bash
#!/bin/bash

apt update -y
apt upgrade ufw sshguard unattended-upgrades wget curl git zip unzip tree -y
ufw --force enable
ufw allow 22,25,80,443

apt install lamp-server^ -y
a2enmod http2 deflate expires

apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext -y

cat <<-EOF >> "$HOME"/.profile
    set -x
    complete -r
    export web_application_root="/var/www/html"
    export -f full_apache_restart
    full_apache_restart() {
        find "$web_application_root"/* -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \+
        find "$web_application_root"/* -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \+
        chown -R www-data:www-data "$web_application_root"/
        systemctl restart apache*
    }
EOF
source "$HOME"/.profile 2>/dev/null

# Set DB credentials with PHPMyAdmin
# Set Apache virtual host
# Set SSL certificate
```

How to execute the last directive "Set SSL certificate" in a free or gratis way, without paying money?

Comment: Let's Encrypt can provide a CA-signed certificate for an internet-facing website, but they do have their own technical process for it. Link: https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Must I first configure a virtual host before the certificate or can I first start with the certificate?

Comment: Perhaps this should be a new question.

Comment: The documentation for certbot - the automation tool that works with Let's Encrypt - says that your website needs to be online and reachable on port 80 - plain HTTP. I don't know if this is a hard requirement, but if it is, you'll need the virtual host to be configured and the site to be up and running.

Comment: "_I don't know if this is a hard requirement_" - it is if you're going to be using http authentication to LE, @Haxiel

Comment: But there is DNS authentication too, hence you can fully get a certificate without any website running.